# How to drop a table and remake it with more columns in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I've got this code. It does what I want, but it only works the first time I run it while the second time around it enters an infinite loop for some reason

Using FastApi and SQLAlchemy with MySQL

As an alternative to this, just to avoid the [XY issue](https://xyproblem.info/), what I am actually intending to do is make a table that contains variable columns (as populated by table "Attributes"). This could be a view, but I haven't really found a way to make a view that contains everything I want.
The endgoal is to connect my database with all relevant columns and rows in a single view or table and connect that to a software called Altium

```
def get_altium_plugin():
    engine.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS altium_plugin")
    
    aRows = session.query(Attributes).group_by(Attributes.name).all()

    cRows = session.query(Component_Attributes).all()

    concat = " "
    x = 0
    while x < len(aRows):

        concat = concat + (aRows[x].name + " VARCHAR(20), ")

        x = x+1
        print(concat)

    concat = concat[:-2]

    engine.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS altium_plugin (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT," + concat + ")")

    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 1
    while x < len(aRows):
        while y < len(cRows):
            if cRows[y].attribute_id == aRows[x].id:
                dbstring = "INSERT INTO altium_plugin (" + aRows[x].name + ") VALUES ('" + cRows[y].value + "')"
                engine.execute(dbstring)
                print("X :" + str(x) + ", Y: " + str(y) + ", " + dbstring)
                z = z + 1
            y = y+1
        y = 0
        x = x+1

    rows = session.query(Altium_Plugin).all()
    return rows
```

I've got the above code, I've tried doing it with non-raw sql and that throws errors, I've done it directly in the SQL side as a script and it works with that raw sql, but the second time that you run this def after starting the python script it gets caught by the

```
    engine.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS altium_plugin")
```

And just loops infinitely, or at least it doesn't continue beyond that point while trying to process something

EDIT: It seems that after running the code once, I'm no longer able to use scripts directly within MySQL Workbench until I stop my python. The engine is probably continuing to work with SQL but without doing anything other than taking up space and processing power, how can I tell the engine to stop without also killing the engine outright?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> DROP TABLE ...
> ```
>
> ... just loops infinitely

I wouldn't be surprised to find the occasional
lock outstanding if you [query](https://serverfault.com/questions/36260/how-can-i-show-mysql-locks) the locks table.

An ALTER or DROP will have to acquire an Exclusive
lock before it can begin.
It doesn't loop, it just hangs,
patiently waiting for the lock to be granted.
I didn't notice any COMMIT or ROLLBACK statements in your code.
Dropping the TCP connection,
or bouncing the backend DB daemon,
are other (more violent) ways of releasing locks,
including Reader locks.
Notice that your interactive workbench
can hold un-committed transaction locks, as well.

Recommend you COMMIT before attempting [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language#DROP_statement).